# Add Clone to a rust liquid template

Tags: rust

I'm following the tutorial [here](https://fasterthanli.me/articles/image-decay-as-a-service) for tide.  It all works up to the point where we have to add a state to the request.  I'm getting an error that `Template` (from liquid templates, which goes in tide's state) does not implement `Clone`. The new version of tide requires state to implement `Clone`.  I try to implement one, but it says I'm not allowed to implement a trait for an imported thing.  How to fix this?  I'm brand new to rust (day one).

I'm guessing I should create a wrapper that points to the `Template`, and implement a shallow clone on that?  But I have no idea how to do that "rustily", whether that's the right approach, or if I would run into ownership problems that way.

Code:

```
use async_std::fs::read_to_string;
use liquid::{Object, Template};
use std::{clone::Clone, error::Error, str::FromStr, collections::HashMap};
use tide::{http::Mime, Response, StatusCode, Request};
pub type TemplateMap = HashMap<String, Template>;
#[derive(Clone)]
struct State {
    templates: TemplateMap,
}
```

Error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `liquid::Template: std::clone::Clone` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:11:5
   |
11 |     templates: TemplateMap,
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected an implementor of trait `std::clone::Clone`
   |
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::clone::Clone` for `std::collections::HashMap<std::string::String, liquid::Template>`
   = note: required by `std::clone::Clone::clone`
   = note: this error originates in a derive macro (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
```

Comment: Paging [@fasterthanlime](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1021683/fasterthanlime)...

Comment: You should at least post the full error, preferably also add relevant snippets of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`liquid::Template` wraps a `Vec<Box<Renderable>>` which makes cloning difficult atm, directly in the crate or via a newtype.  A good short term workaround is to wrap it with an `Arc` which provides shallow cloning for any type.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is a known annoyance in Rust. The programmer cannot implement a trait for a type that he does not own, or rather one cannot implement a trait for a type outside of the crate that either defines the type, or defines the respective trait — this is to ensure that no two competing implementations of the same type could ever exist which could lead to problems.

The common solution is indeed the unelegant one you suggest: wrap the type into a “newtype” essentially creating a struct that contains only this type, thus having created a new type that is identical at runtime, and implement it for your own type.

This will then most likely involve some extra indirection in your code to access the contained type and might involve some boilerplate being redone, but rest assured that this will have no influence on the generated code and that all these are zero-ops.

You can read more about [the trait orphan rules here](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/b4a4fu/what_are_the_technical_reasons_for_the_orphan_rule/).